# read variable from file is out of alignment and extra line

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/tmp/files.txt
FIELDNAME=/tmp/fieldname.txt

num=$(wc -l < $FIELDNAME)

#to read fieldname.txt content
FILE1=$1
cat $FILE1 > FILE2
value=$(<FILE2)

#to create empty lines
yes '' | sed $num\q >> $FILES

#to add fieldname content into files.txt
I=0
for fieldname in $value
do
    echo "Line number $((I++)) --> $fieldname"
    sed -i -e "i\input $fieldname " $FILES
    sed -i -e 's/^/    /' $FILES
    #to remove empty lines
    sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' $FILES
done

sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' $FILES
```

my script name is script.sh and this is how I call my script:

```
./script.sh fieldname.txt
```

The expected result would be:

```
    input abc
    input def
    input ghi
```

But the output I get is out of alignment and more than 3 lines like below:

```
    input ghi
        input def
    input ghi
            input abc
    input ghi
        input def
    input ghi
            input abc
    input ghi
        input def
    input ghi
            input abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how `sed` works -- when run a sed command against a file, it reads through the entire file, and applies the edit rules to *every* line (unless the rules have a line "address" that restricts where they apply). So in your example, you start with a file that has just three blank lines, and run `sed -i -e "i\input $fieldname "` on it, it adds a line that says e.g. "input abc " before *each of those three lines*. Thus, you have a file that looks like this:

```
input abc 

input abc 

input abc
```

(You can't see it, but there's a blank line at the end.) Them, you run `sed -i -e 's/^/    /'`, and it adds four spaces to the front of *every* line (including the blank ones):

```
    input abc 

    input abc 

    input abc
```

Then, you run `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`, which actually does what you expect -- it removes the lines with nothing but spaces, leaving:

```
    input abc 
    input abc 
    input abc
```

Then, in the next iteration of the loop, you run `sed -i -e "i\input def "`, which again puts that new line before each of the existing lines:

```
input def 
    input abc 
input def 
    input abc 
input def 
    input abc
```

And then `sed -i -e 's/^/    /'` again adds 4 spaces to every line (including the ones that already had spaces):

```
    input def 
        input abc 
    input def 
        input abc 
    input def 
        input abc
```

...etc. This is not doing what you want *at all*.

If I understand what you're trying to do, `sed` is really the wrong tool for the job. Rather than trying to edit a an existing file, what you seem to want is to just create a new file, adding to it line-by-line. You can do that quite easily like this:

```
: >"$FILES"    # This empties the file (in case there's something there from last run)

I=0
for fieldname in $value
do
    echo "Line number $((I++)) --> $fieldname"
    echo "    input $fieldname" >>"$FILES"    # Append a line to the end of the file
done
```

If you don't need to print the "Line number..." stuff, or can send it to the standard error output instead of standard output (which is generally where you should send status info, even if it's not actual errors), you can make it even simpler:

```
I=0
for fieldname in $value
do
    echo "Line number $((I++)) --> $fieldname" >&2    # The >&2 redirects to standard error
    echo "    input $fieldname"
done >"$FILES"    # Just send *all* standard output from the loop into the file
```

In either cases, you don't need `num`, or the output from `yes` to preload the file.

There are a bunch of other things here that look like bad practices. For one thing, variable references should almost always have double-quotes around them, like `"$FILES"` in my examples above. This prevents them from being unexpectedly split into multiple "words", and/or expanded as filename wildcards. I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out common mistakes like this.

Note that I didn't do this with `$value` (`for fieldname in $value`), because in that case you're depending on the shell splitting the variable's value into words... which isn't particularly safe. Do you really want to loop over the *words* in the input file, or do you want to loop over *lines* instead? If you want lines, don't use that `for ... in` construct, use a `read` loop:

```
I=0
while read fieldname
do
    echo "Line number $((I++)) --> $fieldname" >&2
    echo "    input $fieldname"
done <"$FILE1" >"$FILES"    # Read input from $FILE1, write output to $FILES
```

See [BashFAQ #001: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more info.

As @Kusalananda pointed out in a (now-deleted) comment, if you are doing this line-by-line and don't need the "Line number..." output at all, you could do this with `sed`. But not in a shell loop, just letting `sed` itself scan through the input file adding "`input`" to each line as it goes:

```
sed 's/^/    input /' "$FILE1" >"$FILES"
```

In any case, you're currently copying $FILE1 to a file literally named "FILE2", then reading that into a variable named `value`... and none of that is necessary; whatever you do should just read directly from the original file.

Another note: use lower- or mixed-case variable names, instead of all-caps names. There are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings to the shell and/or other tools, and if you use one of those by mistake, weird things can happen.